# A directed graph colored path problem?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, np

**Given:** A rooted, directed, a-cyclic graph $G$. Let $r_0$ be the root node and $t_0$ be another target node. Each node in $G$ is assigned a non unique id/color ($ID_i),\ 1<i<N$ for some integer N.

**Problem:** Is there a directed path from $r_0$ to $t_0$, such that for some $ID_x$ there is no node in that path with $ID_x$ as its $ID$. In other words, the nodes in the path do-not cover all the $IDs$.

**Comments:** Clearly the problem is in $NP$ since if we are given such a path we can easily verify it. I suspect the problem is also in $P$ and can be solved in polynomial time. But, I am struggling to find an algorithm for the same.

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple approach: for each $1 \le i \le N$ (I assume that the $<$ in the question are typos) run depth-first or breadth-first search ignoring nodes coloured $i$.

Slightly more advanced approach: use a matrix-based all-pairs reachability algorithm, but rather than record a Boolean `isReachable` or a numeric `shortestDistance` record a bitmap of which colours can be avoided.

Comment: the first algorithm only seems polynomial if the colours are given in unary.  (Although OP asks for a specific colour so that would still be polynomial)

Comment: @Taemyr, yes-ish. IMO it's a reasonable assumption that $N \le |V|$, but I concede that this isn't explicit in the question or the answer.

Comment: Even if N≤|V| you are still outside of polynomial time.  Input size for N is O(log N) - hence the requirement for unary.

Comment: @Taemyr, I'm also assuming that $G$ is encoded in the input, since otherwise there are very few graph algorithms which are poly-time. (Or even if $G$ isn't, if the colouring is then it's $\Omega(N|V|)$).

Comment: @Taemyr If we want to take all considerations then $N$ could also simply be a costant and so does not affect the complexity of the algorithm... the OP did not specify whether he has a "concrete problem" in mind which is modelled by this graph and this could have implications on the range of $N$ or whether or not it should be considered constant.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Peters second comment adequatly explained what my misconception was.

Comment: To save anyone else from pointing it out, I made a mistake in my last comment: it should be $\Omega(|V| \lg N)$.